# Using react-router with webpack to build app, i got a 'noscript' tag. How can i fix this?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router

Before build with webpack:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Router, browserHistory} from 'react-router';
import routes from './routes';

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router routes={routes} history={browserHistory} />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

run the app, and result:

[image: the correct result]

but when i run `webpack build`, i got this:

[image: the wrong result]

but when I remove `history={browserHistory}` and build with webpack, it's working.(the react-router version is V2.4.0)

I don't know why, hope your answer so much!

Comment: You might have to do a "npm install history --save" for this to work. I remember having this issue and it was because I didn't have this installed.

Comment: @TonyTaiNguyen Thanks for your answer, I have been install `history` yet, but it doesn't work for me.